# How to calculate draw power from specs for a UPS

Tags: maintenance, ups

We recently installed some new blade servers and we have 'overloaded' our current UPS (APC Smart UPS 3000). We bought an identical UPS to balance out the load, however, we did not have another 30 Amp socket in our server room to support it. 
I have been asked to figure out if it's 'safe' for a 125V|30A plug (with an adapter) to be plugged into a 125V|20A socket. I was told to calculate the 'draw' power of the UPS and to check the spec sheets, but I'm completely new to this so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to compare/calculate.

http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SUA3000RM2U

If someone can point me in the right direction (even reading), that'd be awesome!

Comment: Have you considered consulting an electrician?

Answer (score 2):

> I have been asked to figure out if it's 'safe' for a 125V|30A plug
>   (with an adapter) to be plugged into a 125V|20A socket.

Absolutely not. If you were doing that and a safety inspector came knocking, you'd be torn to bits.

There's a good reason that different spec circuits have different plug/socket form factors. Subverting those differences is ill-advised.

Comment: How could I calculate max draw from the spec sheet? (just so I could defend my answer?)

My options are to get an plug adapter 30amp/20amp adapter (which I hear is unsafe) or ask the technicians to change the wires/breakers/socket faceplate.

Comment: @Justin Your current line of inquiry is inappropriate. It does not matter what the max draw is. If you have a 30A load and a 20A socket, you're going to need to have an electrician come in a get you a new 30A circuit. That's all there is to it.

Comment: To be clear, there's a reason APC put a 30A socket on that model. You have no choice but to assume that it can and will draw 30A.